How can you access the dataframe from a ggplot component wrapper?
The ggplot book gives this example:
geom_mean <- function() {
  list(
    stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "bar", fill = "grey70"),
    stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", geom = "errorbar", width = 0.4)
  )
}
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, cty)) + geom_mean()
ggplot(mpg, aes(drv, cty)) + geom_mean()

Is it possible to adapt this example so that geom_mean() can directly access the dataframe column mapped to x (i.e. mpg$class or mpg$drv)? [Without having to pass it as an extra argument, obviously -- that feels rather clunky.]

Could you clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve?

@stefan I needed a variant of scale_*_gradientn that ensures that the scale is centered at zero. So I was planning to compute max(abs(df$foo)) and use that to set the limits.

I see. It would of course help if you provide a reproducible example which reflects your real use case. Perhaps adding limits = \(x) max(abs(x)) * c(-1, 1) to the scale is sufficient to achieve your desired result.
